# What commands would be required to export selected records from a MySQL database to a SQLite database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I would like to write a script that supports the following workflow.

1. given: a defined set of queries (select statements with table joins) that return sets of data from a single MySQL database
2. create: a SQLite database that contains the information (tables, data) required to returned the same results to the same set of queries sent in step 1.

Outside of select, delete, and update, I am relatively unfamiliar with SQL, so I would appreciate specific command line or SQL syntax... anything required beyond installing SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abe, this doesn't answer your question but might help you get started. You can export the database using `mysqldump` with `--complete-insert` (since sqlite does not support multi-row / compound inserts), then use `sqlite3_exec()` to import the dump to SQLite

Answer (score 2):

This's an half answer but can be usefull also for other kind of DB.
mysqldump has the option "compatible" to control the standard compliance of the sql dumped.
From the "mysqldump --help" execution:

```
  --compatible=name   Change the dump to be compatible with a given mode. By
                      default tables are dumped in a format optimized for
                      MySQL. Legal modes are: ansi, mysql323, mysql40,
                      postgresql, oracle, mssql, db2, maxdb, no_key_options,
                      no_table_options, no_field_options. One can use several
                      modes separated by commas. Note: Requires MySQL server
                      version 4.1.0 or higher. This option is ignored with
                      earlier server versions.
```